# How to grep all xml files that do not begin with "<"

Tags: grep, find

How can I find all xml files in the current directory and all sub directories, that do not *start with* `<` in the first line.

I have tried this, but the `grep` doesn't work:

```
find . -type f -name '*.xml' | grep "^[^<]" | head -n 1
```

Comment: What are your criteria for identifying "all xml files"? Are you assuming *.xml

Comment: When you say "all xml files", is that in the current directory, in the current directory and all sub directories, or in the entire filesystem?

Comment: are you tied town to `grep` only, or is piping it through `head` an option? If so it's a piece of cake to just loop over all files and check for an unsuccessful `grep` after `head -n 1` and then print the file name.

Comment: Please update your question with this new information. Otherwise it just gets lost in comments

Comment: @roaima; it's done ;)

Comment: Can I suggest giving an example of what you do or don't want to match? Because I'd suggest that an XML that _doesn't_ start with `<` isn't actually XML at all, it's just something that looks a bit like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To grep the first line of each file and print if they match you can use xargs and awk

```
find . -type f -name "*.xml" -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} awk 'NR==1&&!/^</' {}
```

To print the filename of the files

```
find . -type f -name "*.xml" -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} awk 'NR==1&&!/^</{print FILENAME}' {}
```

Comment: Thanks but taht gives the xml files that begins with "<"
I want files that do not begin with “<”

Comment: @Bizboss It should give the one that don't.

Comment: @Bizboss Try the new one.

Comment: Maybe the test is on the complete line? I want to test only the first char of the first line.

Comment: @Bizboss What are you talking about? Have you got multiline file names ?

Comment: @don_crissti So they want to grep out the first line of the files, not the actual names of the files ?

Comment: yes don_crissti; you are right.
I want to find the files that begins for example like this:
a<?xml version="1.0"?>
or like that: b<?xml version="1.0"?>

but not the the files beginnug like that : <?xml version="1.0"?>

Comment: @Bizboss Is this right now ?

Comment: @ User112638726: Yes; That was the right solution:
`find . -type f -name "*.xml" | xargs -I{} awk 'NR==1&&!/^</{print FILENAME}' {}`

But I haven't understand all the options :)

Comment: @Bizboss do any of your file names contain spaces? If so this solution may not work reliably. It would be better to use `-print0` for `find` and the `-0` argument for `xargs` to handle these cases.

Comment: @roaima: I have no spaces in file names

Comment: If your files are long, you could add a `NR>1` clause that skips to the next file.

Answer (score 4):

You have some solid answers already, however I'll offer an alternative - the XML spec is quite strict, and files that *don't* start with `<` isn't actually XML at all.

So a simple approach might be to simply test if the file is 'valid' or not. All XML parsers can do this, but here's an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings; 
use XML::Twig;

foreach my $filename ( @ARGV ) { 
    eval { XML::Twig -> new -> parsefile ( $filename ); };
    print "File: $filename is not valid XML $@\n" if $@;
}
```

This can oneliner-ify as:

```
perl -MXML::Twig -e 'foreach ( @ARGV ) { eval { XML::Twig -> new -> parsefile ( $_ ) }; print "File: $filename is not valid XML $@\n" if $@;' *.xml
```

If recursive traversal is important, then `File::Find` will also help:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;
use File::Find;

sub check_valid_xml {
    #skip any files that don't end in '.xml'
    next unless m/\.xml$/;   
    #validate this file
    eval { XML::Twig->new->parsefile($File::Find::name); };
    #report errors if detected - parser will abort on invalid XML
    if ($@) { print "File $File::Find::name is not valid XML $@"; }
}

find( \&check_valid_xml, "." );
```

This will detect *any* 'bad XML' which will include the files you've specified in your question.

Comment: An interesting technique, but it's quite possible that it doesn't fit the needs of the situation. Imagine there are 400 *.xml files, and 100 of them are not valid, but 63 of those are bad only because they start with "xml:<" for some dumb reason.  Those 63 could be fixed easily, but you wouldn't want them mixed in with the other 27.  OK, a bit contrived, but I think possible.

Comment: Yes, that is true. It might not fit. On the flip side though, according to the spec you shouldn't fix bad XML. It is supposed to be a fatal condition, and reject the whole lot. I don't know if this directly suits the supplicant,  but it does handle the case in point, and others for "free". The error message will also indicate where the fault is.

Answer (score 3):

If your `awk` supports the nextfile statement (most do):

```
 find . -name '*.xml' -type f \( -size 0 -print -o -exec awk '
   !/^</ {print FILENAME}; {nextfile}' {} + \)
```

Answer (score 1):

```sh
find .//. -name \*.xml -type f -exec head -n1 {} + |
sed -ne:n -e'\|^==> \.//\.|!{H;$!d' -e\} \
    -ex   -e'\|\.xml <==\n|!{G;x;d' -e\} \
          -e's|[^/]*//\(.*\) <==\n[^<]*$|\1|p'
```

`head` lists filenames all on its own. So you can just `-exec` it and have `sed` watch its input for `head`'s report on the names for those files which don't match a `<` in their first line.

If you just want to avoid listing filenames for files whose first *character* is `<` that is as easily done. In fact, with a GNU `grep` it can be easier...

```sh
find .//. -name \*.xml -type f -exec grep -EHaom1 '^.?' {} +|
sed     -ne'\|^\.//\.|!{H;$!d' -e\} \
         -e'x;\|\.xml:|!{G;x;d' -e\} \
         -e's|:[^<]*$||p;$!d;x;s|||p'
```

We shouldn't directly test for the `<` char with `grep` because we might end up testing the third or fourth line if the first begins with a `<`, but what we can do is tell `grep` to stop at 1 `-m`atch for `-o`nly 0 or 1 char at the head of a line. This means `grep` will print our filenames like...

```
.//./path/to/xml.xml:.
```

And so all `sed` must do is ensure it gathers the *entire* filename *(in case it contains newline characters)* and then to test if the last character in the string is `<` if it is not, `sed` strips the last two chars and prints the results.

Answer (score 0):

Pure bash:

```
shopt -s globstar
for i in **/*.c;do
    read -N 1 h < "$i";
    if [[ $h != "<" ]]; then
        # echo "found $i";
        # do stuff with "$i"
    fi;
done
```

`read -N 1` reads a single character from the file, without having to fork/exec anything.  If you just need a list of filenames, use something else that makes it easier to use the `-print0` style.